# Question marks instead of accented letters (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Accented problem!
My website does not display the accented letters from the database. Everything is displayed on my own computet, but on other computer a question mark appears instead of the accented letters! I tried to rewrite the utf character encoding in the database but nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Your title should be a short summary of the problem. The question should include enough detail that people have a reasonable chance of helping you.

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem is going to be that you're not handling character encoding correctly at each level (the DB, the server, the client). [This article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) outlines why that's important. For instance, **just as an example**, perhaps your DB is storing ISO-8859-1 and your server is sending it (unchanged) to the browser, but claiming it's UTF-8. That means characters that are encoded differently in the two encodings don't get handled correclty.

Comment: See "question marks" (not black diamonds) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored